# C++: How can I forward-declare derived classes that appear in a static method of a base class?

Tags: c++, derived-class, forward-declaration

Just doing a simple exercise where I'm translating ideas I learned from another language to C++.

I have an abstract class Number, which has two derived classes, PositiveNumber and NegativeNumber. Number has a static method that *should* create a new instance of either PositiveNumber or Negative number, depending on the sign of its input.

```
#include <iostream>

class Number
{
public:
protected:
    int magnitude_;
public:
    static Number* fromInt(int x)
    {
        if (x >= 0) { return new PositiveNumber(x); }
        else        { return new NegativeNumber(x); }
    }
    int getMagnitude() { return magnitude_; }
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class PositiveNumber: public Number
{
protected:
public:
    PositiveNumber(int magnitude) { magnitude_ = magnitude; }
    void print() { std::cout << magnitude_ << "\n"; }
};

class NegativeNumber: public Number
{
protected:
public:
    NegativeNumber(int magnitude) { magnitude_ = magnitude; }
    void print() { std::cout << "-" << magnitude_ << "\n"; }
};


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Number* x = Number::fromInt(5);
    x->print();

    return 0;
}
```

I know that I need to tell Number that PositiveNumber and NegativeNumber exist, but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried adding

```
class PositiveNumber;
class NegativeNumber;
```

before Number's definition, but that wasn't enough, and resulted in:

```
use of undefined type 'PositiveNumber'
use of undefined type 'NegativeNumber'
```

I'm sure this has a simple answer, but I'm pretty new to debugging C++ stuff, so I'm pretty lost. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `fromInt()` needs to know what constructors `PositiveNumber` and `NegativeNumber` have, so forward declarations are not enough.  You need to break up the declaration and definition of `Number::fromInt()`, and then you can move the definition underneath the declarations of `PositiveNumber` and `NegativeNumber`.

Also, don't forget to `delete` the object that `fromInt()` `new`'s.  Which also means adding a virtual destructor to `Number` so derived destructors can be called correctly from a base `Number*` pointer.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Number
{
protected:
    int magnitude_;
public:
    static Number* fromInt(int x);

    virtual ~Number() {}

    int getMagnitude() { return magnitude_; }
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class PositiveNumber: public Number
{
public:
    PositiveNumber(int magnitude) { magnitude_ = magnitude; }
    void print() { std::cout << magnitude_ << "\n"; }
};

class NegativeNumber: public Number
{
public:
    NegativeNumber(int magnitude) { magnitude_ = magnitude; }
    void print() { std::cout << "-" << magnitude_ << "\n"; }
};

Number* Number::fromInt(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0) { return new PositiveNumber(x); }
    else        { return new NegativeNumber(x); }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Number* x = Number::fromInt(5);
    x->print();
    delete x;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/zhwK0z)